# Vectors are linearly dependent $\iff$ Some vector can be written as linear combination of other vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Robert Messer (2021, *Linear Algebra: Gateway to Mathematics*, pp. [120](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ues3EAAAQBAJ&pg=PA120), [123](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ues3EAAAQBAJ&pg=PA123)):

> **3.8 Definition:** *A finite set $\{\boldsymbol v_1, \boldsymbol v_2, \ldots, \boldsymbol v_n \}$ of vectors in a vector space is* **linearly independent** *if and only if the equation $$r_1 \boldsymbol v_1 +r_2 \boldsymbol v_2 +\ldots +r_n \boldsymbol v_n = \boldsymbol 0$$ implies that $r_1=r_2=\ldots=r_n=0$. If it is possible for the equation to hold when one or more of the coefficients is nonzero, the set is* **linearly dependent**.

> **3.9 Theorem:** *The set $\{\boldsymbol v_1, \boldsymbol v_2, \ldots, \boldsymbol v_n \}$ of vectors in a vector space is linearly dependent if and only if one of the vectors can be written as a linear combination of the other vectors in the set.*

I have a doubt about Theorem 3.9:

Isn’t it the case that the set $\{\boldsymbol 0\}$ linearly dependent but $\boldsymbol 0$ can’t be written as a linear combination of any other vectors in the set (because there aren’t any other vectors in the set)?

Comment: The characterization that is given in the second image needs $n>1$ to be true, since you have identified the exception. Often, things like $\{\mathbf{0}\}$ are treated as special cases. If $S=\{\mathbf{v}\}$ is a singleton set containing a vector, it is linearly dependent if and only if $\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$.

Comment: $0$ is a linear combination of the vectors in the empty set, since an empty sum is zero.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks to you I learned something new today: "empty sum". I have never heard of it. It is an interesting concept.

Comment: @Quantum, next up: the empty product, which is $1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think your comment should be edited as *the* answer (provided the question is not a duplicate, which I didn't check yet but I shall do). It could include [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum), and even, if you like to "drive the point home", mention that the empty set itself is linearly independent.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Is that (1) a definition (that Messer should have stated); or (2) a result (that Messer should have stated and proven using other definitions & results already given)?

Comment: The proof is, for all $x$, $x$ plus an empty sum equals $x$, hence, an empty sum equals zero. This is not a result in Linear Algebra, it's much more basic than that, so Messer might not have seen a need to state or prove it. But, since not everybody is aware of it, it would have been a good idea to mention it. I should add that as I haven't seen the book, I don't know whether or not Messer stated it in some other part of the book.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the definition of 3.9 implies that there is more than one vector in the set since it says the word vectors, not a vector. At the bottom of page 123, they provide an example:

"As a consequence of this theorem, it becomes very easy to check whether a set of **two** vectors is linearly independent. Simply observe whether or not one vector is a scalar multiple of the other. After all, this is the only way to form a linear combination with the remaining vector. Thus $\{(-3, 8, 7), (0,0,0)\}$ is linearly dependent in $\mathbb{R}^3$"

Comment: So is the set $\{(1,0,0)\}$ not linearly independent?

Comment: I think walkar's comment put it more elegantly than I did, but this would not be applicable since you only have one vector. If it was {(1), (0), (0)} then you could express the first as a product of the other two sets (a linear combination).

Comment: To drive the point home, this reference says "Note that linear dependence and linear independence are notions that apply to a collection of vectors. It does not make sense to say things like 'this vector is linearly dependent on these other vectors,' or 'this matrix is linearly independent.'" https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Linear_Algebra/Interactive_Linear_Algebra_(Margalit_and_Rabinoff)/02%3A_Systems_of_Linear_Equations-_Geometry/2.05%3A_Linear_Independence

Comment: There is so much wrong here. "a product of the other two sets" – $(0)$ and $(0)$ aren't sets, $(1)$ is not their product, and a product is not a linear combination. "It does not make sense to say things like 'this vector is linearly dependent on these other vectors'" – that will come as news to everyone who has ever learned linear algebra, as one says things like "$(1,1)$ is linearly dependent on $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$" all the time. And a *collection* of vectors might contain two or more vectors, but it might just contain one vector, or it might not contain any vectors at all (continued)

Comment: (continued), that's the way we use the word in mathematics.

Comment: You're correct. I was trying to emulate the example from the text where they showed that the collection of vectors {(-3,8,7), (0,0,0)} are linearly dependent because the latter is a linear combination of the former. I said set when I should have said set (or collection) of vectors and I should have said you can get the vector 0 as a linear combination of the vector 1. Again, this just follows from the example they gave in the book. I'll edit the comment.

Comment: To follow up on the second point about the collection of vectors: in what context does the link I referenced not make sense? When I search for any reference on linear independence, it is describing the relationship between a sequence, set, or collection of vectors. Even in the example where you mentioned (1,1) being linearly dependent on (1,0) and (0,1), aren't we describing a sequence/ collection/set of vectors? As I understand, you've described the standard bases for R2. What would be the pedagogical aim in stating this if it were not true? (Continued)

Comment: (Continued) I could be missing something important here, especially because the original question was asking about the set containing 0. But yes, I was just trying to understand because I am referencing something that one might use to learn linear algebra, so if I'm walking away with the incorrect understanding, then I'd like to know why the thing I referenced said something that you found surprising

Comment: You wrote, "It does not make sense to say things like 'this vector is linearly dependent on these other vectors....' " I say it makes perfect sense to say, for example, the vector $(1,1,1)$ is linearly dependent on $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,1)$, where it's understood that what this means is $(1,1,1)$ is linearly dependent on $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,1)\}$. Similarly, it makes sense to say $(2,2,2)$ is linearly dependent on $(1,1,1)$. Also: if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to include @Gerry in it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That makes sense. I was quoting this book https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Linear_Algebra/Interactive_Linear_Algebra_(Margalit_and_Rabinoff)/02%3A_Systems_of_Linear_Equations-_Geometry/2.05%3A_Linear_Independence and I think they are just being explicit because they are introducing the topic to whoever is reading.

Answer (score 0):

I think Definition 3.8 should probably mention that the vectors should be nonzero as this would be a problem in any linearly independent set of vectors being considered.
$$\lambda_1\mathbf v_1 + ... + \lambda_n\mathbf v_n + \lambda_{n+1}\mathbf 0 = \mathbf 0$$

Then $\lambda_{n+1}$ could be anything and it would have no consequence on what values $\lambda_{1},...,\lambda_{n}$ take

Comment: I don't understand. Doesn't your example correctly show that by Definition 3.8, $\mathbf v_1$,  $\mathbf v_2$,  $\mathbf v_n$, and $\mathbf 0$ aren't linearly independent?

Comment: @user182601 This answer is wrong indeed. There is no "problem" with $v_{n+1}=0,$ precisely because $\lambda_{n+1}$ can be anything hence can be $\ne0,$ which (together with $\lambda_1=\dots=\lambda_n=0$) "correctly shows that by Definition 3.8, $v_1,\dots,v_n,0$ are not linearly independent".

Comment: No, this is what I meant. You need to exclude that the vectors could be zero. Having a zero vector included in the list means they are not linearly independent because it doesn't give the implication that ALL the lambda's are $0$


@AnneBauval I don't understand what you mean by "There is no "problem" with  $v_{n+1}=0$[...]" and then you have just repeated what I said.

Comment: I just agreed with @user182601's comment and (therefore) disagreed with your answer, i.e. I claim 3.8 *and 3.9 and its proof* hold even if one of the vectors is $0.$ I agree with you that in that case the vectors are linearly dependent, and I disagree with your wish to exclude that case from 3.8 and/or 3.9 for some (non-existing) "problem". Definition 3.8 doesn't need to "mention that the vectors should be nonzero" for them to be independent. It would be redundant. It is a consequence of the definition.